# Is there an efficient algorithm to find whether an integer is a prime power?

Tags: integers, factoring

There's a sentence in the current version of the [Wikipedia page for Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Shor%27s_algorithm) which states: *we can use efficient classical algorithms to check if $N$ is a prime power*. No reference is provided to support it.

Is this true? I've tried to look around for such an algorithm but didn't find much.

There is [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-the-number-is-a-prime-power-number/) providing code to solve this problem, which states that the time complexity is indeed $O(\log N)$, but they also don't provide references, so I'm not sure how reliable it is. The idea of the algorithm seems to be to simply loop over all primes smaller than $\sqrt N$, and each time try to divide until you get to $1$. The reasoning seems sound, but I'm not sure how you verify the complexity of this procedure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that if a number $N$ is a power of a prime $p$ it will be of the form:

$$N=p^i \ ,$$

Since $p$ is prime, $p \geq 2$ which implies $i \leq \log_2 N$.

We can compute the $i$th roots of $N$ for each $2\leq i \leq \log_2 N$ and check if the resultant number is integer, and eventually if it is a prime. The complexity of these two steps is higher than $O(\log N)$ but they are ignored in practice.

The complexity of the computation of roots should be equal to that of arithmetic operations like the multiplication, but it is hard to give a precise estimate of it (depends on number representation, precision, etc).

For checking the primality, if needed, you can use the Miller-Rabin primality test which takes $O(k\log N)$, where $k$ is the number of iterations needed. Since you check for numbers $\leq \sqrt N$, it will be $O(k\log \sqrt N)=O(k\log N)$, so as you can see the asympthotic analysis leads to higher complexities.

The fact is that often you can avoid the majority of these steps because at a certain point you can exclude that a number is integer for instance

Comment: You can try to find the smallest prime factor p and check if N is a power of p, as long as this is faster than calculating the roots of N.

Answer (score 17):

See:

Daniel J. Bernstein. *[Detecting perfect powers in essentially linear time](http://cr.yp.to/papers/powers-19971106-retypeset20220326.pdf)*, Mathematics of Computation 67 (1998), 1253–1283.

Here, "linear" means "linear in $\log N $". Specifically, the complexity is $\left(\log N\right)^{1 + o(1)}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.